# UBUNTU : Oracle SQL Developer won't connect to local database, OCI library won't load

Tags: oracle, docker, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

For my projects I dockerise Oracle.

I already done it on Windows and on OSX (Intel) without any trouble.

On Monday, I (finally) got a Linux laptop (Ubuntu).

I am facing an issue when trying to connect SQL Developer to the Oracle instance (localhost:1596/ORCLCDB)

I can connect to the database with SQL+
But I had to add the following instruction
`DISABLE_OOB=ON` in the sqlnet.ora of the instant client (21_6).

I have the following FATAL NI connect error in the logs

```
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016681071Z Fatal NI connect error 12170, connecting to:
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016688189Z  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.19.0.1)(PORT=39328))
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016693632Z 
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016698433Z   VERSION INFORMATION:
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016703279Z  TNS for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016708617Z  Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016714084Z  TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016719419Z   Version 21.3.0.0.0
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016724426Z   Time: 13-JUL-2022 05:28:22
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016729415Z   Tracing not turned on. Process Id = 1694
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016734226Z   Tns error struct:
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016739288Z     ns main err code: 12535
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016743996Z     
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016749310Z TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016755291Z     ns secondary err code: 12606
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016761390Z     nt main err code: 0
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016766428Z     nt secondary err code: 0
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016771329Z     nt OS err code: 0
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016776144Z 2022-07-13T05:28:22.914379+00:00
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016780964Z opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (1694) as a result of ORA-609
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016785848Z 2022-07-13T05:28:22.914772+00:00
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016790717Z Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_ora_1694.trc:
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016796032Z ORA-00609: could not attach to incoming connection
2022-07-13T05:28:23.016801170Z ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

So I am trying to instruct SQLDeveloper to use the instant_client but it does not work

```
Testing the Instant Client located at /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_6
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
  Driver version: 21.6.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... Failed:
  Error loading the native OCI library
  The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system propertyjava.library.path contains the entries from the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Check it to verify that
  the expected native library directory /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_6 is present and precedes any other client installations.
  java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: If you manage to turn your full process in a sequence of bash commands, this would help others to reproduce and debug. Below, my solution which tries to be more reproduceable (but on SQLDev cli, not GUI).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I like to use the command line version of SQLDeveloper, namely sqlcl (this IS SQLDeveloper, but as a command line). If this fits your needs, then do:

To get sqlc:

```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   cd ~/bin
   wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/java/sqldeveloper/sqlcl-latest.zip
   unzip sqlcl-latest.zip
```

To launch the container and connect to it:

```
   docker run -d --name my_oraclexe_container \
     -p 1521:1521\
     -p 5500:5500\
     -e ORACLE_PWD=mypwd\
     container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe

   export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Doracle.net.disableOob=true"

   # Interactive session
   ~/bin/sqlcl/bin/sql SYS/mypwd@localhost:1521 as sysdba
```

Here, running a scripted command:

```
   ~/bin/sqlcl/bin/sql SYS/mypwd@localhost:1521 as sysdba <<- _EOF_
       -- SQL Oracle
       SET ENCODING ISO-8859-15;
       SELECT 'Connection is successful' from dual;
       QUIT
   _EOF_
```